# An error occurred while recording the microphone and speaker sound mix using NAudio

Tags: c#

Recording the microphone and speaker sound mix with NAudio prompted me "File XXXX is being used by another process and therefore cannot access the file"

Here is my recording code:

```
if (!Directory.Exists(audioCaptureDirectory))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(audioCaptureDirectory);
        }
        outputFilePath = audioCaptureDirectory + filename;
        soundcard = outputFilePath + "_soundcard.wav";
        microphone = outputFilePath + "_microphone.wav";
        mixed = outputFilePath + "_mixed.wav";


        waveSourceSpeakers = new WasapiLoopbackCapture();
        waveFileSpeakers = new WaveFileWriter(soundcard, waveSourceSpeakers.WaveFormat);
        waveSourceSpeakers.DataAvailable += (s, a) =>
        {
            waveFileSpeakers.Write(a.Buffer, 0, a.BytesRecorded);
        };
        waveSourceSpeakers.RecordingStopped += (s, a) =>
        {
            waveFileSpeakers.Close();
            waveFileSpeakers.Dispose();
            waveFileSpeakers = null;
            waveSourceSpeakers.Dispose();
        };
        waveSourceSpeakers.StartRecording();


        waveSourceMic = new WaveIn();
        aveFileMic = new WaveFileWriter(microphone, waveSourceMic.WaveFormat);
        waveSourceMic.WaveFormat = waveFileSpeakers.WaveFormat;
        waveSourceMic.DataAvailable += (s, a) =>
        {
            aveFileMic.Write(a.Buffer, 0, a.BytesRecorded);
        };
        waveSourceMic.RecordingStopped += (s, a) =>
        {
            aveFileMic.Close();
            waveSourceMic.Dispose();
            waveSourceMic = null;
            aveFileMic.Dispose();
        };

        waveSourceMic.StartRecording();
```

The function where I try to mix my 2 wav files looks like this:

```
using (var reader1 = new AudioFileReader(soundcard))
            using (var reader2 = new AudioFileReader(microphone))
            {
                reader1.Volume = 2.0f;
                reader2.Volume = 2.0f;
                var mixer = new MixingSampleProvider(new[] { reader1, reader2 });
                WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile16(mixed, mixer);
            }
```

VS prompted me to report an error starting with the line "Using (var Reader1 = new AudioFileReader(Soundcard))". The error was "file XXXXX is being used by another process and therefore cannot access this file"

Comment: `waveFileSpeakers = new WaveFileWriter(soundcard, waveSourceSpeakers.WaveFormat);` the file was opened there

Comment: This is not C code. Perhaps you meant to use `C#` tag?

Comment: I released waveFileSpeakers when I stopped recording `waveSourceSpeakers.RecordingStopped += (s, a) =>
            {
                waveFileSpeakers.Close();
                waveFileSpeakers.Dispose();
                waveFileSpeakers = null;
                waveSourceSpeakers.Dispose();
            };
            waveSourceSpeakers.StartRecording();`